# Split Using cSplit R

Tags: r, text, split, multiple-columns, splitstackshape

In my dataset I have a column whit hash-tags and names separated by comma (i.e., #xxx, @rrr, ...). I want to split it in one column for each has-tag/name. I used:

```
library(splitstackshape)
hash <- cSplit(indt = as.data.table(dados), splitCols = dados$hashtags, direction = "wide", sep = ",", drop = FALSE)
```

and got the error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(indt, , splitCols, with = FALSE) : 
>     column(s) not found: #ForaManoel, @FernandinhaDoRT:, #ForaManoel, #FicaEmilly, @PortalLaRavena:, @emillyaraujoof, #ForaManoel, @opakaique:, #FORAEMILLY, #foramanoel, #BBB17, #ForaEmilly, #ForaManoel, @oDanielFontes:, #ForaManoel, @HugoGloss:, #F

Any help?

Tks,

Ricardo.

Comment: Try with `cSplit(dados, "hashtags", drop = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah. Works great!